# mySQL WHERE IN with array

Tags: php, mysql

I have one-dimensional-array $abc.

```
$abc = array (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
```

I want to use it in WHERE IN

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE columnA IN ()

while (){
$def[] = $row['def'];  
}
```

When I use simple IN('$abc') I have a response - Undefined variable: def

How to do it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `implode()` function:

```
$abc = array (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
$str = implode(',', $abc);
```

Now you can use `$str` in `IN` clause.

---

Learn more about [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

The [**implode**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) make it easy for you

```
$query='SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE columnA IN ('.implode(',', $abc).')';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$abc = array (90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99);
$imploded = implode(",", $abc);
//then your query
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE columnA IN ($imploded)
```

Hope it helps